# Error while launching any .launch file

Tags: roslaunch, ros-kinetic, ubuntu, ubuntu-xenial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I'm getting this error

```
machine.env_loader must have been assigned before creating ssh child instance
The traceback for the exception was written to the log file
```

when running any .launch file on my local machine( I'm not using ssh at all)

I'm using ubuntu 16.04 + ROS kinetic

I have to admit that I missed up with /etc/hosts and ROS_MASTER_URI but I don't know what I did wrong :)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/303898/error-while-launching-any-.launch-file/) by [jafar_abdi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25259/jafar_abdi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 221 on 2018-09-20

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-09-20**:
I'm not sure it's actually related, but what did you do to `/etc/hosts` and what is the value of `ROS_MASTER_URI` now?

**Comment by [jafar_abdi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25259/jafar_abdi/) on 2018-09-20**:
ROS_MASTER_URI::  http://jafar-abdi.local:11311, /etc/hosts 127.0.0.1       jafar-abdi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After following this tutorial the error has gone [Click](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2016/06/change-hostname-ubuntu-16-04-without-restart/)

---

Originally posted by [jafar_abdi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25259/jafar_abdi/) with karma: 221 on 2018-09-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dinesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/26847/dinesh/) on 2020-05-20**:
what exactly did u did? i also followed that link, but its not working. shouldn't it be only changing the hostname of computer?